# Connecting to a smb server on my iMac

Tags: networking

I figured this would be as easy as

```
 sudo mount.cifs //192.168.10.101/Media /mnt/media/imac -o user=house,password=12345
mount error(13): Permission denied
```

On the Mac I created a share called `Media` and an account called house.

I have the account "house" access to the Media folder.

What I'm I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I routinely use the following to mount a share on macOS.

```
sudo mount.cifs //Milliways.local/Images /mnt/Image -o user=XXX
```

This assumes the Mac share is correctly configured (which is off-topic here)
**AND** the mount point exists.

NOTE `user` is the Mac username to connect as.

Comment: Thanks dude. I must of tried that command but for some reason it only works when someone else tells you it hahahaha

Answer (score 0):

sudo mount -t cifs //Asus/store_n_go /mnt/

https://www.looklinux.com/how-to-mount-samba-share-smbfs-in-linux/

To get it. I think, just trying.

Answer (score 0):

mine works this way:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o uid=1000,gid=1000,user=pi,pass=`cat /home/pi/samba.cred` //myserver/media /home/pi/shared/data/media
```